# Import own swift framework

Tags: ios, swift

I created a swift framework and now i want to import it in my application.

I did `import BiometricAccessControl` in my ViewController but xcode not recognizes my classes.

How can i solved it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a problem of access control policy.
By Default, your type(class,enum,struct) and their member(property,subscript,method)'s access control level is internal,which is visible inside your framework,if you want to expose it(namely,API) to other modules, you could try to add public modifier to your class or their member.For Example:

```
public class MySwiftComponent {
    public var publicInt:Int?
    private var privateInt:Int?
    internal var internalInt:Int?
}
```

Totally, there are three access level : public ,internal and private (internal is default)

Comment: this is the issue, thanks i will change this property of my classes